# parse.com sending transaction emails

Tags: ios, parse-platform, mandrill

I want to send an email whenever someone makes a purchase in my ios App. What is the code to be able to do so?

I tried following the instructions here:
https://www.parse.com/questions/sending-email-with-mandrill-on-ios

but the first part does not make sense. Where do we put the javascript code?

Another requirement - I want to be able to change the email text whenever without releasing an app upgrade.

Comment: Hey is that anywhere close to what you're looking for?  It's kind of generic since I'm not sure the details of your app and how far along you are...

Answer (score 0):

You put the JavaScript in your back-end web server hosted using the CloudKit APIs at parse.com: [Parse JavaScript API](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide).  From your question, I'm presuming the back-end will send the email.

If the Parse back-end sends the email, there's no need to push an App Store update to your iOS app to change the email.  You may, however, need to push an update to your Parse CloudKit app, depending upon how you've designed the back end.